# Why is this code removing only some array elements but not others?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a checkio task where you have to calculate the number of islands in a given 2 dimensional array, where an island is defined as a group of "1"s that are connected horizontally, diagonally or vertically (http://www.checkio.org/mission/task/info/calculate-islands/python-3/). The code I've written is supposed to first remove a position from the search space (I don't know if I'm using the right word, I don't know anything about algorithms) if the number in the position is 0. Problem is the code only removes some positions that have the number 0 on it but not other positions that have 0s. Here's the code:

```
def checkio(data):

    result = ''
    count = 0
    boo = True
    searchspace = []
    specificsearchspace = []
    def search(y,x):
            result = ''
            count = 0
            if data[y][x] == 0:
                searchspace.remove([y,x])
            if data[y][x] == 1:
                specificsearchspace.extend([[y,x+1],[y+1,x-1],[y+1,x],[y+1,x+1]])
                for i in specificsearchspace:
                    if data[i[0]][i[1]] == 0:
                        searchspace.remove(i)
                        specificsearchspace.remove(i)
                    if data[i[0]][i[1]] == 1:
                        searchspace.remove(i)
                        specificsearchspace.remove(i)
                        count += 1
                        search(i[0],i[1])
                result += str(count) + ','
                return result
    for y in range(len(data)):
        for x in range(len(data[y])):
            searchspace.append([y,x])
    print searchspace
    for f in searchspace:
        print search(f[0],f[1])
    print searchspace

#These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert checkio([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]) == [1, 3], "1st example"
    assert checkio([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]) == [5], "2nd example"
    assert checkio([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]) == [2, 3, 3, 4], "3rd example"
```

The output is this:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
None
None
None
None
1,
None
None
None
None
None
[[0, 1], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 0], [4, 2], [4, 4]]
```

Comment: How about using `filter()` instead of ad hoc loop and `remove`? two birds one stone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are changing the size of the list while iterating over it, every time you call .remove()

For a very small example of this, try doing this:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in items:
    if item == 2:
        items.remove(item)

    print item
```

You'll see that this prints 1, 2, 4, and 5. Where did 3 go? Well, what happened was that Python held a pointer to where in the list it had iterated, but then the list changed underneath that pointer, sort of like pulling the rug out from under someone.

There are a few good ways to tackle this: you can either loop backwards from length down to zero, or you can subtract 1 from your index any time you remove(). You may also do a while loop and set a flag that says "during this loop through, we found some zeroes" and then if that flag is false, exit the while loop. Not very efficient, but effective.

Comment: The OP can just wrap the `range(len([sequence varible]))` with the built in `reversed()` method and keep the rest of the code intact.

Comment: Oh! I get it now, thank you for explaining. How would I subtract 1 from my index?

Comment: I was mistaken in my (now deleted) comment previously. @JasonSperske has the correct idea above.

Comment: Is this code correct: items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i=0
while i < len(items):
    if items[i] == 2:
        items.remove(items[i])
        i -= 1
    print items[i]
    i += 1

Comment: Correction: items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i=0
while i < len(items):
    if items[i] == 2:
        items.remove(items[i])
    print items[i]
    i += 1